# What are good CLI tools for JSON?

Tags: json, xslt, command-line, xpath

### General Problem

Though I may be diagnosing the root cause of an event, determining how many users it affected, or distilling timing logs in order to assess the performance and throughput impact of a recent code change, my tools stay the same: `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `tr`, `uniq`, `sort`, `zcat`, `tail`, `head`, `join`, and `split`. To glue them all together, Unix gives us pipes, and for fancier filtering we have `xargs`. If these fail me, there's always `perl -e`.

These tools are perfect for processing CSV files, tab-delimited files, log files with a predictable line format, or files with comma-separated key-value pairs. In other words, files where each line has next to no context.

### XML Analogues

I recently needed to trawl through Gigabytes of XML to build a histogram of usage by user. This was easy enough with the tools I had, but for more complicated queries the normal approaches break down. Say I have files with items like this:

```
<foo user="me">
    <baz key="zoidberg" value="squid" />
    <baz key="leela"    value="cyclops" />
    <baz key="fry"      value="rube" />
</foo>
```

And let's say I want to produce a mapping from user to average number of `<baz>`s per `<foo>`. Processing line-by-line is no longer an option: I need to know which user's `<foo>` I'm currently inspecting so I know whose average to update. Any sort of Unix one liner that accomplishes this task is likely to be inscrutable.

Fortunately in XML-land, we have wonderful technologies like XPath, XQuery, and XSLT to help us.

Previously, I had gotten accustomed to using the wonderful `XML::XPath` Perl module to accomplish queries like the one above, but after finding a [TextMate Plugin that could run an XPath expression against my current window](http://ditchnet.org/xmlmate/), I stopped writing one-off Perl scripts to query XML. And I just found out about [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) which is installing as I type this and which I look forward to using in the future.

### JSON Solutions?

So this leads me to my question: are there any tools like this for JSON? It's only a matter of time before some investigation task requires me to do similar queries on JSON files, and without tools like XPath and XSLT, such a task will be a lot harder. If I had a bunch of JSON that looked like this:

```
{
  "firstName": "Bender",
  "lastName": "Robot",
  "age": 200,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "123",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "1729"
  },
  "phoneNumber": [
    { "type": "home", "number": "666 555-1234" },
    { "type": "fax", "number": "666 555-4567" }
  ]
}
```

And wanted to find the average number of phone numbers each person had, I could do something like this with XPath:

```
fn:avg(/fn:count(phoneNumber))
```

### Questions

1. Are there any command-line tools
   that can "query" JSON files in this
   way?
2. If you have to process a bunch of
   JSON files on a Unix command line,
   what tools do you use?
3. Heck, is there even work being done
   to make a query language like this
   for JSON?
4. If you do use tools like this in
   your day-to-day work, what do you
   like/dislike about them? Are there
   any gotchas?

I'm noticing more and more data serialization is being done using JSON, so processing tools like this will be crucial when analyzing large data dumps in the future. Language libraries for JSON are very strong and it's easy enough to write scripts to do this sort of processing, but to really let people play around with the data shell tools are needed.

#### Related Questions

- [Grep and Sed Equivalent for XML Command Line Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing)
- [Is there a query language for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777455/is-there-a-query-language-for-json)
- [JSONPath or other XPath like utility for JSON/Javascript; or Jquery JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859033/jsonpath-or-other-xpath-like-utility-for-json-javascript-or-jquery-json)

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a pure XSLT 2.0 solution, which parses JSON, converts it to an XML document and then can process this XML document, meaning that then it can evaluate any XPath expressions on this XML document. This is really powerful.

Comment: In the interest of technical accuracy, I must point out that it's [Bender *Rodríguez*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bender_%28Futurama%29).

Comment: DefiantJS (http://defianjs.com) does exactly these kind of stuff. This lib extends the global object JSON with a search method, with which it's possible to query JSON structure with XPath.

Comment: There is a collection of command-line tools for navigating and querying JSON here: https://ilya-sher.org/2018/04/10/list-of-json-tools-for-command-line/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I just found this:

http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

"jq is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor."

2014 update:

@user456584 mentioned:

> There's also the 'json' command (e.g. 'jsontool'). I tend to prefer it over jq. Very UNIX-y. Here's a link to the project: github.com/trentm/json –

in the **`json`** README at http://github.com/trentm/json there is a long list of similar things

> - **jq**: http://stedolan.github.io/jq/
> - **json:select**: http://jsonselect.org/
> - **jsonpipe**: https://github.com/dvxhouse/jsonpipe
> - **json-command**: https://github.com/zpoley/json-command
> - **JSONPath**: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/, http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/Javascript
> - **jsawk**: https://github.com/micha/jsawk
> - **jshon**: http://kmkeen.com/jshon/
> - **json2**: https://github.com/vi/json2
> - **fx**: https://github.com/antonmedv/fx

Comment: There's also the 'json' command (e.g. 'jsontool'). I tend to prefer it over jq. Very UNIX-y. Here's a link to the project: https://github.com/trentm/json

Comment: I've been eyeing JQ for a day or so... and cannot find any way to have the tool output something other than JSON. This makes its value in extracting data for scripts very limited. It is great for filtering existing JSON into more JSON.

Comment: well, yes and no...  try something like this https://gist.github.com/tingletech/9823267

Comment: @ZachGarner, JQ does support string interpolation - thus you can generate output which is not JSON. See e.g. [my answer on UNIX SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254243/1131) for an example.

Answer (score 7):

I have created a module specifically designed for command-line JSON manipulation:

https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli

[image]

- **FLEXIBLE** - THE "swiss-army-knife" tool for processing JSON data - can be used as a simple pretty-printer, or as a full-powered Javascript command-line
- **POWERFUL** - Exposes the full power and functionality of underscore.js (plus underscore.string)
- **SIMPLE** - Makes it simple to write JS one-liners similar to using "perl -pe"
- **CHAINED** - Multiple command invokations can be chained together to create a data processing pipeline
- **MULTI-FORMAT** - Rich support for input / output formats - pretty-printing, strict JSON, etc [coming soon]
- **DOCUMENTED** - Excellent command-line documentation with multiple examples for every command

It allows you to do powerful things really easily:

```
cat earthporn.json | underscore select '.data .title'
# [ 'Fjaðrárgljúfur canyon, Iceland [OC] [683x1024]',
#   'New town, Edinburgh, Scotland [4320 x 3240]',
#   'Sunrise in Bryce Canyon, UT [1120x700] [OC]',
# ...
#   'Kariega Game Reserve, South Africa [3584x2688]',
#   'Valle de la Luna, Chile [OS] [1024x683]',
#   'Frosted trees after a snowstorm in Laax, Switzerland [OC] [1072x712]' ]

cat earthporn.json | underscore select '.data .title' | underscore count
# 25

underscore map --data '[1, 2, 3, 4]' 'value+1'
# prints: [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

underscore map --data '{"a": [1, 4], "b": [2, 8]}' '_.max(value)'
# [ 4, 8 ]

echo '{"foo":1, "bar":2}' | underscore map -q 'console.log("key = ", key)'
# key = foo
# key = bar

underscore pluck --data "[{name : 'moe', age : 40}, {name : 'larry', age : 50}, {name : 'curly', age : 60}]" name
# [ 'moe', 'larry', 'curly' ]

underscore keys --data '{name : "larry", age : 50}'
# [ 'name', 'age' ]

underscore reduce --data '[1, 2, 3, 4]' 'total+value'
# 10
```

It has a very nice command-line help system and is *extremely* flexible.  It is well tested and ready for use; however, I'm still building out a few of the features like alternatives for input/output format, and merging in my template handling tool (see TODO.md).  If you have any feature requests, comment on this post or add an issue in github.  I've designed out a pretty extensive feature-set, but I'd be glad to prioritize features that are needed by members of the community.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful tool.  In cast it's obvious to everyone but me, if you read an input JSON file that contains an object, it's named "data".  So if you do something using (for instance) process command, you will need to refer to the property like "data.myProp.myValue".

Answer (score 5):

One way you could do is to convert it to XML. Following uses two perl modules (JSON and XML::Simple) to do fly-by conversion:

```
cat test.json | perl -MJSON -MXML::Simple -e 'print XMLout(decode_json(do{local$/;<>}),RootName=>"json")'
```

which for your example json ends up as:

```
<json age="200" firstName="Bender" lastName="Robot">
  <address city="New York" postalCode="1729" state="NY" streetAddress="123" />
  <phoneNumber number="666 555-1234" type="home" />
  <phoneNumber number="666 555-4567" type="fax" />
</json>
```

Comment: I had considered the possibility of converting to XML, performing any XPath queries and XSL transformations, and then piping to other shell utilities. I didn't know it'd be so simple. I'll have to look into these Perl modules.

Comment: This still doesn't really feel like a first-class JSON tool, though. You're essentially just using a programming language that has good support for JSON and XML and then dropping back into XML tools for the real processing.

Answer (score 5):

There is also interactive terminal tool — [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx)

Pipe into fx any JSON and anonymous function for reducing it.

```
$ echo '{...}' | fx [code ...]
```

Start interactive mode without passing any arguments:

```
$ curl ... | fx
```

[image]

- https://github.com/antonmedv/fx

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this insane project [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk/). It is design to filter through JSON input from the command line. Check [resty](https://github.com/micha/resty) as well for a command line REST client that you can use in pipelines that may come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I discovered that JSON can easily be `eval`-ed with Python:

```
$ python -c "json=eval(open('/json.txt').read()); print len(json['phoneNumber'])"
2
```

Though the method will obviously fail if the JSON input contains nulls.

Comment: Python 2.6+ has a [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module built-in, and older versions can use [simplejson](http://www.undefined.org/python/).  I wouldn't recommend eval for this.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: I agree that using the method in a complex environment where you receive input from an untrusted source is dangerous, but as a console one-liner that might be an option.

Comment: @newtover it's just as easy to do using the json module in the standard lib:
`python -c "import json;x=json.loads(open('json.txt').read());print len(x['phoneNumber'])"`

Comment: @ori, json became a part of the standard library only in 2.6, but even several months ago I made most of the developent on 2.5. By the way, now I prefer demjson as a JSON library.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [**`f:json-document()`**](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-json-document.xsl?view=markup&sortby=date) from the [**FXSL 2.x library**](http://fxsl.sf.net).

Using this function it is extremely easy to incorporate JSon and use it just as... XML.

For example, one can just write the following XPath expression:

```
f:json-document($vstrParam)/Students/*[sex = 'Female']
```

and **get all children of `Students` with `sex = 'Female'`**

**Here is the complete example:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="f xs"
 >
 <xsl:import href="../f/func-json-document.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vstrParam" as="xs:string">
{

  "teacher":{
    "name":
      "Mr Borat",
    "age":
      "35",
    "Nationality":
      "Kazakhstan"
             },


  "Class":{
    "Semester":
      "Summer",
    "Room":
      null,
    "Subject":
      "Politics",
    "Notes":
      "We're happy, you happy?"
           },

  "Students":
    {
      "Smith":
        {"First Name":"Mary","sex":"Female"},
      "Brown":
        {"First Name":"John","sex":"Male"},
      "Jackson":
        {"First Name":"Jackie","sex":"Female"}
    }
    ,


  "Grades":

    {
      "Test":
      [
        {"grade":"A","points":68,"grade":"B","points":25,"grade":"C","points":15},

        {"grade":"C","points":2, "grade":"B","points":29, "grade":"A","points":55},

        {"grade":"C","points":2, "grade":"A","points":72, "grade":"A","points":65}
       ]
    }


}
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "f:json-document($vstrParam)/Students/*[sex = 'Female']"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on any XML document (ignored), the correct result is produced**:

```
<Smith>
   <First_Name>Mary</First_Name>
   <sex>Female</sex>
</Smith>
<Jackson>
   <First_Name>Jackie</First_Name>
   <sex>Female</sex>
</Jackson>
```

Comment: This is interesting. I haven't seen FXSL before (no offense!), so I'll have to play around with it before I fully understand this example (honestly I'm a lot more experienced with XPath than with XSLT). But this seems a bit verbose to fit my need for an easy-to-use CLI toolkit.

Comment: @jasonmp85 Why would be: `f:json-document($vstrParam)/Students/*[sex = 'Female']`  verbose?  Just using the `f:json-document()` function is the opposite of verbose... :)

Comment: Well that snippet alone isn't too verbose, but the required JSON-inside-an-XSL-stylesheet is. But with a bit of code to wrap this library a usable CLI tool could emerge.

Answer (score 1):

> *Fortunately in XML-land, we have wonderful technologies like XPath, XQuery, and XSLT to help us.*
> *[...]*
> *So this leads me to my question: are there any tools like this for JSON?*

If you ask me, [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) is exactly what you're looking for.

> Xidel is a command line tool to download and extract data from HTML/XML pages or JSON-APIs, using CSS, XPath 3.0, XQuery 3.0, JSONiq or pattern templates. It can also create new or transformed XML/HTML/JSON documents.

```
$ xidel -s "input.json" -e '
  $json/avg(
    count((phoneNumber)())
  )
'
2
```