# How to replace a word after some specific tags in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am in a situation where I need to replace some specific word after a match is found. 
The condition is the tag should start with "detailSelection", after that wherever there is WORD1, I need to replace it with WORD2.

This is a small snippet from a big file, I have to do it in hundreds of file.

```
                         "detailSelection": {
                                        "name": "Alarm Detail",
                                        "type": "form-operation",
                                        "requireSelection": true,
                                        "dataSelection": {
                                            "typeSelection": {
                                                "domain": "ossm",
                                                "package": "WORD1",
                                                "type": "WORD1"
                                            },
```

OUTPUT Should be like:

```
                   "detailSelection": {
                                        "name": "Alarm Detail",
                                        "type": "form-operation",
                                        "requireSelection": true,
                                        "dataSelection": {
                                            "typeSelection": {
                                                "domain": "ossm",
                                                "package": "WORD2",
                                                "type": "WORD2"
                                            },
```

Comment: [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1955505/608639), [What are good CLI tools for JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933126/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, you need to use sed command

```
sed -i 's/WORD1/WORD2/g' filename.txt
```

-i will do this replace inside the file. In other words, it will alter the file. If you want to create a new file, then

```
sed 's/WORD1/WORD2/g' filename.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: This would replace "WORD1" with "WORD2" _everywhere_ it appears, not just when it appears within "detailSelection" blocks, so fails the OP's requirements.

Comment: @yoga. This would replace all the appearance of WORD1 which is not the case here as mentioned by Stephen P as well.